# How one can determine an expression for these homogeneous coordinates

Tags: geometry

In this link: http://planetmath.org/ProofOfPappussTheorem. The author write: *No three of the four points .... are collinear, and therefore we can choose homogeneous coordinates such that...*.

I am asking on how this is possible in view point of algebra, i.e., **How one can determine an expression for these homogeneous coordinates**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical proof [without loss of generality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) (although it doesn't say so). Pappus' theorem is an incidence theorem, and incidence relations are invariant under projective transformations. A projective transformation is uniquely defined by four points and their images, no three of which may be collinear. So if there are four points in the construction which are known not to be collinear, then there exists a projective transformation which takes these to any four points one cares to choose, as long as no three of these are collinear either. The author of the proof can therefore perform the computation using these specific coordinates, and know that this proof is still general, i.e. it still applies to all possible configurations prior to the transformation.